# String vs Varchar Hive Query Performance

Tags: string, performance, hive, hiveql, varchar

I have this table with 5 mill records, around 25 columns and most of them are String type. When I make a query, it lasts around 47 sec to fetch the results. **I've 2 GB of space for each String column (because I dont know how to reduce that value)**, the max length record is just around 32k characters for one column, the other ones have way more less than that (7,18,50).

To get a better query performance, ***I copied that table, but instead of String, I used Varchar(1000) and varchar(50000)*** for that long record mentioned above, in all STring columns. I thought this would get me a faster fetch, but it takes almost the double of the time.

As my understanding, im using way more less space using varchar, but somehow this is not happening. **Under the same conditions, should I get a better response using varchar instead of string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any performance difference between `string` and `varchar` but best option is used as string, `varchar` is also stored internally as string.

Here are some excellent thread on detail comparison for both:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/48260/hive-string-vs-varchar-performance.html

[Hive - Varchar vs String , Is there any advantage if the storage format is Parquet file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191793/hive-varchar-vs-string-is-there-any-advantage-if-the-storage-format-is-parqu)